# Matrix Eigenvector in Opposite Direction to WolframAlpha?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been asked to find the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for the following matrix:
$$
A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which I have calculated the Eigenvalues to be:
$$
    \lambda = 0,1,2
$$

And the respective Eigenvectors to be:
$$
    E_0 = (1,0,-1)\\
    E_1 = (0,1,0)\\
    E_2 = (1,0,1)\\
$$

I have checked my answer against the results from WolframAlpha. Everything is the same except for one Eigenvector:
$$
    E_{0_{me}}= (1,0,-1)\\
    E_{0_{wolfram}}= (-1,0,1)
$$

I can see that the vectors are essentially the same, just in opposite directions. Do I have the right answer? Does it matter if the Eigenvectors are in opposite directions?

By extension, would the following be correct also?
$$
    E_1 = (0,-1,0)
$$

.
Thanks!

Comment: You should look up the definition of eigenvector, and ask (if your textbook does not say this already) whether a scalar multiple of an eigenvector is again an eigenvector. The equation defining (possible) eigenvectors for$~\lambda$ is a linear _homogeneous_ equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any non-zero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector (with the same eigenvalue), since if $Ax=\lambda x$ then $A(cx)=c(Ax)=c(\lambda x)=\lambda (cx)$.

Actually a bit more is true: The set of eigenvectors (plus the zero vector) corresponding to a fixed eigenvalue is a subspace of the given vector space, so any linear combination  of eigenvectors (not equal to zero vector) corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ is another eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.